# Google API credentials expire after one week

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

When I backup from WHM to my Google Drive account it works for one week only, after that authentication fails. If I recreate the credentials it works again for another week. Is there a way for this credential to never expire? I am following instructions from this link to create everything:

https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/backup/how-to-configure-google-drive-as-a-backup-additional-destination/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the documentation [experation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

[image]

You will notice it says  `OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.`

Solution is to set your application to production mode and have it verified then your refresh tokens will not expire after a week.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will test it again and check after 1 week if it works